# Ajax-y sites load sloooowly or not at all. [Ubuntu/Mint]

Tags: networking, browser

About two months ago I reinstalled Ubuntu onto my desktop machine. Since doing so I've had a lot of problems with certain websites and very slow or complete loading. It *seems* to be related to use of AJAX -- gmail is heavily affect, general stackexchange pages generally not (but submitting forms to stackexchange can be), slashdot/wired/torontoist/duckduckgo not much, various gov of canada form-heavy website: terribly so.

I don't believe it's hardware related as this issue emerged only after reinstalling Ubuntu, and I have a win7 partition on this machine that also works fine. The Mint partition on this box suffers the same issue.

I've googled for this (which was, yes, slow), and found very little: [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1322482) posting has very similar symptoms to what I'm experiencing, but a totally different network setup: I'm on a home network behind a home router, and already using auto DHCP addresses.

I'm not sure what my next steps for diagnosing this problem should be, any help would be totally appreciated.

Comment: I believe this is appropriate: http://xkcd.com/979/